# R 3d surface plot with factor variables

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I have a pretty simple question but just can't get my head around. How do I create a 3D surface plot with grid for the following data.

```
x = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun")
y = c("2010","2011","2012")
z = matrix(seq(1:18),nrow=3)
```

I have tried something like this, but still can't get what I want.

```
persp3d(x, y, z)
plot3d(x, y, z)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that `persp3d()` gives when the `x` is a factor or character variable means it will only take numeric in `x` (and probably in `y` and `z` too) so `x, y` must be numeric:

```
x <- 1:6
```

Corresponding month names:

```
month <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun")
```

I retract my previous statement here, now that I understand how `plot3d` maps z-values at positions defined by `x` and `y` so `y` can stay as is, but has to be numeric:

```
y = c(2010,2011,2012)
```

In addition, `nrow(z)` must be the same as `nrow(x)`, again this is clear from the error thrown when one attempts the contrary. So:

```
z = matrix(seq(1:18),nrow=6)
```

Plot your surface without the default axes: (from here, the approach is very similar to how we do custom axes with ordinary 2d graphs in R)

`library(rgl)
persp3d(x, y, z, axes=F, ylab="", zlab="")
box3d()`

Finally add your axes:

`axis3d(edge='x++', at=x, labels=month, tick=T)
axis3d(edge='y--', at=y, labels=y, tick=T, pos=c(0,0,0), line=-1)
axis3d(edge='z+-', at=as.integer(range(z)), labels=as.integer(range(z)), tick=T)`

[image]

Comment: It's not quite what I expected. 1).The "x" displays as "1,2,3,4,5,6", instead of "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun". 2).It's a scatter plot, instead of a surface plot. Thank you.

Comment: Thats's right, my initial assumptions of how `plot3d` works were incorrect. See updated answer.